# Create a link that will open a workbook to a specific cell in the desktop app

Tags: excel

I want to create a link that 1) opens excel desktop app (ms-excel:ofe|u|) and 2) takes you directly to a cell/range in a sheet.

If the file is already open, the link will direct you to the specified range. If the file is closed, then Excel will open the file before directing you to the range.

Is there a method to use the URI Scheme to open the excel desktop app to a specific cell or range using links?

Sources
[Office URI Schemes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/office-uri-schemes#appendix-c---uri-scheme-registration-template-for-ms-excel-scheme)

Comment: Still hoping someone knows more!

Answer (score 1):

in google sheets (as you tagged your question) you do it like this:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/♥/edit#gid=♦&range=♣
```

where:

```
♥ = spreadsheet id
♦ = gid of sheet
♣ = cell or range
```

example:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JBAb5do2RW2r5VNDE-ndPDQcBp766s12MCSyJ8kmasY/edit#gid=0&range=A1
```

Comment: I apologize, google sheets should not have been tagged on this question. Thanks for your response